# outlook rule to convert incoming email to plain-text

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email-filter

We all have those people who decide to put a ton of junk mark-up in their emails and make it nearly impossible to read. What I'd like to have is a rule in Outlook 2010 that as soon as an email comes from a certain person (or probably group) it automatically converts it to plain-text instead of html. Any ideas?

Comment: It would be better to do this on the server, but I understand that's not always feasible.

Answer (score 6):

I "solved" this same problem by assigning a mail rule to pick up only the specific problem email/s, and moves it to "Junk". 
In junk, all emails are converted to plain text.

Thus I read these problem emails in my junk folder, which is much better than the status quo of outlook "not responding" for a minute every time I accidentally preview the problem email.

EDIT: I also added a notification alert to the mail rule so that I wouldn't "miss" the email

Answer (score 4):

If you are concerned about the display and do not really need to convert see here for instructions to "Read as Plain Text"
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/831607

Comment: Hrm that's much simpler, and doesn't alter the original messages.

Comment: is there a way to use that with a rule, or somehow tie it to just one person?

Comment: @aron.duby the method described here is global, not for one user. Use my VBA method, perhaps creating a copy of the image laden message to just apply it to one user.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit a message with VBA. According to the MSDN, if you set the [`_MailItem.BodyFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.bodyformat.aspx) property to `olFormatPlain` it will discard all formatting.

[This article on using VBA as a more powerful alternative to the Outlook filtering rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa155733(v=office.10).aspx) should set you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

A rule that incorporates the VBA required can be found here, with ItemAdd and NewMailEx alernatives.

http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=62

```
Sub ConvertToPlain(MyMail As MailItem)
Dim strID As String
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem

strID = MyMail.EntryID
Set objMail = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(strID)
objMail.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
objMail.Save

Set objMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

For the ItemAdd and NewMailEx solutions you can limit the conversion by testing for the SenderName or SenderEmailAddress like this.

```
If objMail.SenderName = "Mailer, HTML" Then
    objMail.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
    objMail.Save
End if
```

You can find the SenderName with this. (For unknown reasons one of my senders does not have a SenderEmailAddress.)

```
Sub Addresses_CurrentItem()

Dim olMail As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set olMail = ActiveInspector.currentItem

If olMail Is Nothing Then
' might be in the explorer window
    If (ActiveExplorer.selection.Count = 1) And _
     (ActiveExplorer.selection.Item(1).Class = olMail) Then
        Set olMail = ActiveExplorer.selection.Item(1)
    End If
End If
On Error GoTo 0

If olMail Is Nothing Then

MsgBox "Problem." & vbCr & vbCr & "Try again " & _
"under one of the following conditions:" & vbCr & _
    "-- You are viewing a single email message." & vbCr & _
    "-- You have only one message selected.", _
vbInformation
Exit Sub
End If

If TypeOf olMail Is MailItem Then

Debug.Print "  Sender    : " & olMail.SenderName   
Debug.Print "  SenderEmailAddress: " & olMail.SenderEmailAddress & vbCr

End If

End Sub
```