# How to display emails from a specific contact in text plain

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook-2007, email-client

I'm recieving emails in html from a specific contact, but I want to receive only from him mails in plain text.

I have checked the box in Tool > Trusted Center > Email Security > []Read all standard mails in plain text, but I do not want to remove the format from all mails.

How do I achieve this?

- I'm using Microsoft Outlook 2007 with Exchange Mail Server.
- Windows XP Profesional (I know it is obsolete)

Answer (score 1):

Some answers can be found in this thread on this forum :
[outlook rule to convert incoming email to plain-text](https://superuser.com/questions/460199/outlook-rule-to-convert-incoming-email-to-plain-text).

**Solution 1 : Change message format to plain text via a rule**

Use the Rules Wizard to create a rule using the "run a script" action to call
this VBA procedure :

```
Sub ConvertToPlain(MyMail As MailItem)
Dim strID As String
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem

strID = MyMail.EntryID
Set objMail = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(strID)
objMail.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
objMail.Save

Set objMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

For the ItemAdd and NewMailEx solutions you can limit the conversion by testing for the SenderName or SenderEmailAddress like this.

```
If objMail.SenderName = "Mailer, HTML" Then
    objMail.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
    objMail.Save
End if
```

You can find the SenderName with this:

```
Sub Addresses_CurrentItem()

Dim olMail As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set olMail = ActiveInspector.currentItem

If olMail Is Nothing Then
' might be in the explorer window
    If (ActiveExplorer.selection.Count = 1) And _
     (ActiveExplorer.selection.Item(1).Class = olMail) Then
        Set olMail = ActiveExplorer.selection.Item(1)
    End If
End If
On Error GoTo 0

If olMail Is Nothing Then

MsgBox "Problem." & vbCr & vbCr & "Try again " & _
"under one of the following conditions:" & vbCr & _
    "-- You are viewing a single email message." & vbCr & _
    "-- You have only one message selected.", _
vbInformation
Exit Sub
End If

If TypeOf olMail Is MailItem Then

Debug.Print "  Sender    : " & olMail.SenderName   
Debug.Print "  SenderEmailAddress: " & olMail.SenderEmailAddress & vbCr

End If

End Sub
```

More info can be found in the article
[How to process incoming messages in Microsoft Outlook](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=62).

**Solution 2 : Use a rule to move mail to "Junk"**

In junk, all emails are converted to plain text.

Comment: ill test now, anyway ill upvote for that big research.